# ¿como pasar valores de un select a una pagina php con ajax y sin boton?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

hola tengo un problema tengo unos `select` dentro de una tabla html los cuales los genero para cambiar el estado de una orden de servicio pero no se como pasar el valor seleccionado a una pagina php donde se hará la consulta update , sin necesidad de elegir una opción y luego darle clic a un botón para enviar lo que seleccione, quiero simplemente que al elegir otra opción se mande automáticamente y haga la actualización

este es uno de mis tantos `select` que tengo en la tabla html, si se pudieran enviar sin un form estaría mejor

```
 <form method='post' id='update'>
       <select name='estado' id='estado'>
                <option value=''>Seleccionar</option>
                <option value='en curso'>En curso</option>
                <option value='pendiente'>Pendiente</option>
                <option value='cerrada'>Cerrada</option>
            </select>
      </form>
```

este es mi código con el que pretendo enviar la opción seleccionada de mi select option:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
  $('#estado').on('change',function(){                                      

    $.ajax({                        
       type: 'POST',                 
       url : 'scripts/update_orden_servicio_estado.php',                   
       data: $("#update").serialize(),
       success: function(data)            
       {

       }
     });
  });
});
```

y este es mi código donde recibo la variable y hago la consulta:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$estado=$_POST['estado'];

$query= "UPDATE orden_servicio_externo SET estado = '$estado'";
mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Problemas al actualizar".mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error al principio del código estas haciendo `$(document).on(ready)`, debería ser `$(document).ready(function(){});`, después seleccionar el valor del select con `.val();` lo guardas en una variable y la colocas en el data, de esta forma: `data:{value: valor}`, y en PHP lo obtienes como `$_POST['value'];`, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#estado').on('change',function(){                                      
    let valor = $('#estado').val();
    console.log(valor);
    $.ajax({                        
       type: 'POST',                 
       url : 'scripts/update_orden_servicio_estado.php',                   
       data: {value: valor},
       success: function(data)            
       {

       }
     });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='estado' id='estado'>
                <option value=''>Seleccionar</option>
                <option value='en curso'>En curso</option>
                <option value='pendiente'>Pendiente</option>
                <option value='cerrada'>Cerrada</option>
            </select>
```

imagen de mi tabla html con el select
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando selecciono un opción en consola no me aparece nada como en tu ejemplo no esta obteniendo el valor

Comment: Ya hiciste los cambios que te mencioné? te manda algún error?

Comment: ya funciono pero una pregunta mas , acabo de editar mi pregunta subi una imagen de como tengo los select dentro de una tabla como puedo obtener el id con el select ?ya que al elegir una opción me actualiza toda mi tabla por que no lleva un where en la consulta ya que no paso un id, anteriormente hice algo parecido pero con un botón de esta manera

Comment: var id = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[0].innerHTML;

Comment: No puedo ver imágenes aquí donde trabajo :C, a qué id te refieres al de la celda donde esta tu `select`?

Comment: si hace id para que solo actualice el select de la celda que elegí y no todas

Comment: Creo que tendrías que formular otra pregunta, porque no especificas que se tiene que actualizar el mismo select con el que acabas de enviar un ajax, solo pides mandar el valor sin necesidad de oprimir un botón, igual especifica que requieres realizar la búsqueda del select en la celda donde se encuentra.

Comment: ok esta bien deja sigo intentando muchas gracias por tu ayuda